# How to read a file that another process is writing to

Tags: c#

There is a file C:\acme.log that another program (not mine) is writing to. It is a log file, so the program always has it open for writing.

I would like to read the current contents of the log file. I tried

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\acme.log");
FileStream fileStream = fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

This fails with **System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\acme.log' because it is being used by another process.**

I can open the file in Notepad and view its contents. If Notepad can open the file, there should be a way for my program to do it, shouldn't there?

Comment: check out [File.OpenRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_OpenRead_System_String_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the link here:

[Reading a file which is locked by another process](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/viewD21B312F-242A-4038-9E9B-AE6AAB53DAE0.htm)

Here is the code from that link:

```
using (FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream("c:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader logFileReader = new StreamReader(logFileStream))
{

   while (!logFileReader.EndOfStream)
   {
      string line = logFileReader.ReadLine();
      // Your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not `Close` explicitly, but wrap into `using` i.e. `using (FileStream logFileStream = ...) {...}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , could you elaborate more why you would rather use a `using` statement instead of explicitly closing? Do they not achieve the same?

Comment: Thank you. FileShare.ReadWrite seems to be the ticket. Instead of using this code, I added the flag to my code which seems to fix it.

Comment: @Symon: if `new StreamReader(logFileStream)` or`logFileReader.ReadLine()` *throws exception* `logFileStream.Close()` will *not* be executed and and thus stream will not be closed (we'll have *resource leakage*)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for your suggestions, I updated the code to use using statements